# Railo-Tomcat on existing Apache PHP server

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat, railo

I need to run ColdFusion apps on my existing PHP server (Linux).
I installed railo with tomcat on the server, but Railo is hogging all the traffic. I want it installed such that only requests to files within /webapps/ROOT/ go through the Railo server, and all others through the existing php server. The server is not my own, and my installation of Railo is breaking other users' sites.

Is there any way I can do this?

P.S.: I am not very proficient with Linux and the company that owns it has totally crap support, so talking to them is taking one step forward and two steps back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to install `mod_jk` or `mod_proxy` to forward requests from the Apache to Tomcat.

Here's an example with `mod_jk`.

1. Install Tomcat
2. Download the
   [*.war](http://www.getrailo.org/down.cfm?item=/railo/remote/download/3.3.1.000/custom/all/railo-3.3.1.000.war)
   file into `webapps` folder and rename to `railo.war`.
3. Install `mod_jk`
4. Create/edit the `workers.properties` file as belows:

   ```
   worker.list=worker1

   worker.worker1.type=ajp13
   worker.worker1.host=127.0.0.1
   worker.worker1.port=8009
   ```
5. Create a `mod_jk.conf` file:

   ```
   LoadModule          jk_module modules/mod_jk.so

   JkWorkersFile       /etc/httpd/conf/workers.properties
   JkShmFile           /var/log/httpd/jk.shm

   JkLogFile           /var/log/httpd/mod_jk.log
   JkLogLevel          info
   JkLogStampFormat    "[%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y] "

   <VirtualHost *:80>
       ServerName      your.domain.com
       JkMount         /railo/* worker1
   </VirtualHost>
   ```
6. Add a virtual host for Tomcat:

   ```
     <Host name="your.domain.com"  appBase="webapps"
           unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"
           xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">
       <Context path="/railo" docBase="railo"/>
     </Host>
   ```

It means that the request to http://your.domain.com/railo will be forward to Tomcat, at `railo` context and other requests are still served by Apache.

Answer (score 2):

Mod Proxy example (credit Jamie Krug for simplifying this):

**httpd.conf**

```
<Proxy *>
Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Proxy>
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPassMatch ^/(.+\.cf[cm])(/.*)?$ ajp://localhost:8009/$1$2

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName testhost1
    DocumentRoot "/path/to/testhost1"
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.cfm
    ErrorLog "logs/testhost1-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/testhost1-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName testhost2
    DocumentRoot "/path/to/testhost2"
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.cfm
    ErrorLog "logs/testhost2-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/testhost2-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

**server.xml (Tomcat)**

Make sure that these are defined above the definition of LOCALHOST

```
<Host name="testhost1" appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true" xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">
    <Context path="" docBase="/path/to/testhost1" />
</Host>
<Host name="testhost2" appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true" xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">
    <Context path="" docBase="/path/to/testhost2" />
</Host>
```